# Render what camera sees and not first frame

Tags: rendering, camera

Sorry for the noob question, I just can't find the answer anywhere.
I've just setup a few key frames of animation and I happy with it.
However, after the render I noticed that there were a few glitches with some of the cloth physics.

All I want to do now is to move the camera and render what the camera sees in order for me to troubleshoot the scene.  However, each time I press render, it insists on rendering the first frame of the animation key frames.

Surely there's a way I can still render what the camera see and not forcing me to scrub through the key frames to get the camera where I want it?

Regards,
Val

Answer (score 2):

No need to scrub every time from the beginning. You can adjust the range of frames to start rendering (and playing) from however you want. Look in the Properties Panel for the *Output Settings* tab, and adjust the range for the frames you want rendered. Your file is likely starting from the beginning because the start frame is 1 by default. Change this setting to something later in the timeline.

[image]

You can alternatively change this same range setting in the *Timeline Editor* window, which can be found at the bottom of the screen while using the *Animation* Workspace. Changing it in either location changes it in the other.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes, I also stumbled upon that... what I ended up instead was to add another camera that I could use to just go around the scene and do quick 1 frame renders without disturbing any of the other keyframed cameras.. etc..  But again, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a animation that shows this.  When you see the highlighted box your looking through the camera and that's what will be rendered.

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thanks Rick... While I very much appreciate you taking the time to give your explanation with a fantastic little video... that part I knew, it was the fact that the camera would only render the keyframes at any one specific frame number... I just wanted the freedom to move about the scene and render what the camera saw at that moment in time... so I added another camera to the scene and that gave me the flexibility I was after.. Thanks just the same, I always appreciate a helpful community such as this..